# Google authorship on non blog pages?

Tags: search-results, author, google-plus, rich-snippets

Adhering to [Google authorship](https://plus.google.com/authorship) on your blog posts gets a little picture next to your title in the serp, but is it right to also use the authorship tag on normal 'static pages' ie home page, about us, contact etc...

Because this is a company (not personal) website can we use the authoship tag to show our company logo by pointing the authoship tag to a google+ company profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google+ is a young social network and I think you cannot use company for authorship; it must be an employee. But I agree it's not pratical because employee can leave the company.

We must wait Google+ grows to use this kind of possibilities.

More useful information in [this article](http://www.optimum7.com/internet-marketing/google-optimization/pros-and-cons-of-google-authorship-for-businesses.html).